# Typescript with Mongoose Paginate, statics methods

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, pagination

Greetings from Nepal.

I am wondering how you guys do it when you need Paginate Model and statics method in mongoose Model.

To use statics and methods function in mongoose model, I use this code:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document, Model } from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate-v2';

interface IUser {
    username: string;
    hashedPassword: string;
}

interface IUserDocument extends IUser, Document {
    setPassword: (password: string) => Promise<void>;
    checkPassword: (password: string) => Promise<boolean>;
}

interface IUserModel extends Model<IUserDocument> {
    findByUsername: (username: string) => Promise<IUserDocument>;
}

const UserSchema: Schema<IUserDocument> = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    hashedPassword: { type: String, required: true },
});

UserSchema.methods.setPassword = async function (password: string) {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    this.hashedPassword = hash;
};

UserSchema.methods.checkPassword = async function (password: string) {
    const result = await bcrypt.compare(password, this.hashedPassword);
    return result;
};

UserSchema.statics.findByUsername = function (username: string) {
    return this.findOne({ username });
};
UserSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
const User = mongoose.model<IUserDocument, PaginateModel<IUserDocument>>("User", UserSchema);
export default User;
```

How to use statics methods and Paginate at the same time

if I declare type like this
const User = mongoose`.model<IUserDocument, IUserModel>("User", UserSchema);

Then I cannot use **AdminModel.paginate();**

and if I declare type like this
const User = mongoose`.model<IUserDocument, PaginateModel>("User", UserSchema);

Then I cannot use **AdminModel.findByUsername();**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both `PaginateModel` and `UserModel` `extends` the mongoose `Model` so the `intersection` of this two types might work:

```
import {PaginateModel} from "mongoose"

// ...

const User = model<UserDocument, PaginateModel<UserDocument> & UserModel>("User", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

It was really difficult to setup the Package, as it didn't had much about TS
So i used this:

```js
import mongoose, { Model } from "mongoose";

/**
 * Represents a pagination service.
 * This class helps with managing pagination for a given Mongoose model.
 */

export interface PaginatedResponse {
  result: any[];
  hasNextPage: Boolean;
  hasPreviousPage: Boolean;
}

export default class PaginationService {
  private model: Model<any>;

  /**
   * Create a PaginationService instance.
   * @param {mongoose.Model} model - The Mongoose model to paginate.
   */

  constructor(model: Model<any>) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  private _page_size: number = 10; // Default size is 10

  /**
   * Gets or sets the page size.
   * @default 10
   */

  get page_size(): number {
    return this._page_size;
  }

  set page_size(newSize: number) {
    if (newSize <= 0) {
      throw new Error("Size must be a positive number");
    }
    this._page_size = newSize;
  }

  /**
   * Get Paginated Response
   * Next and Previous page as Boolean
   */

  async getPaginatedResponce(page: number): Promise<PaginatedResponse> {
    const totalDocumentsRecords = await this.model.countDocuments({});

    // Calculate the total number of pages
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalDocumentsRecords / this.page_size);

    // Determine if there's page
    const hasNextPage = page < totalPages;
    const hasPreviousPage = page > 1;

    const result = await this.model
      .find()
      .limit(this.page_size)
      .skip((page - 1) * this.page_size)
      .exec();

    const response: PaginatedResponse = {
      result,
      hasNextPage,
      hasPreviousPage,
    };

    return response;
  }
}
```

How to use it? here's how

```js
import PaginationService, {
  PaginatedResponse,
} from "@/services/Pagination/Pagination";

const pagination = new PaginationService(anyMongoModel);
    pagination.page_size = 2;

let page = 1

let paginated_response: PaginatedResponse = await pagination.getPaginatedResponse(page);
```

You can tweek it to handle more scenarios.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/paginator-v1
Or you can use the package.